# Is this proof be correct even though it doesn't use any steps as a consequence of surjectivity?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am following a proof I found online and I am wondering if it actually holds. The problem is:

Show that if $f: A \to B$ is surjective and $H \subseteq B$ then $f(f^{-1}(H))=H$.

[image]

It seems that the manipulations they do in the first section where it is proved that $f(f^{-1}H) \subseteq H$ should have some step as a consequence of $f$ being surjective.

I feel that the same arguments could be made if the "is surjective" is taken out of the proof altogether! Is this proof valid despite that not explicitly having been written?

Comment: It's right there in black and white: "since $f$ is surjective..."

Comment: @TonyK Should have clarified, I was specifically talking about the first step where they prove $f(f^{-1}(H)) \subseteq H$

Comment: The first step doesn't need surjectivity. Only the second step does. But of course you need both steps to complete the proof.

Comment: Surjectivity is only required to allow us to assume $f^{-1}(H)$ is actually defined.  And it wouldn't matter of $f:A\to B$ were not surjective to $B$; only that $f: f^{-1}(H) \to H$ ($f$ restricted to the preimage of $H$) is surjective to $H$.

Comment: @fleablood: $f^{-1}(H)$ is always defined! It is equal to $\{x\in A\;|\;f(x)\in H\}$.

Comment: @TonyK Could you elaborate as to why surjectivity is only required for the second step? I don't quite follow.

Comment: For heaven's sake, Sam! You said it yourself! OK, calm down Tony: The proof shows that $f(f^{-1}(H))=H$ by proving inclusion in both directions, i.e. $f(f^{-1}(H))\subseteq H$ and $H\subseteq f(f^{-1}(H))$. The first inclusion is valid for any $f$, as you suspected; the second inclusion is not necessarily true unless $f$ is surjective. Is that clear?

Comment: @TonyK  Fair enuff.  I was having a brain fart.  I was thinking $f^{-1}(H)= $ the set of all $a$ where $f(a) = h$ for each $h \in H$ and if there were an $h$ with no such $H$ then we could have no $a$ but... nothing wrong with emptysets.  (*fart*).  *BUT* surjectivity to all of $B$ is not relevant.  Only surjectivity to $H$.

Comment: @TonyK I didn't assume it was valid for any $f$ (I didn't write this proof I am simply trying to understand it). I thought the opposite of that. I thought $f$ needed to be surjective for both steps and was confused why the proof made no mention of it. I guess where I am confused now is why f does not need to be surjective for the proof to hold. In Reese's answer below, he claims that one of the steps depends on surjectivity.  Appreciate your patience, this is my first exposure to proof based math so things that seem in your face obvious take a while for me to grasp.

Comment: THere is no requirement that theorem *ONLY* be true if all the hypothesis are true.  The only requirement is that *if* the hypothesis are true then the conclusion must be true.  It's always possible that that conclusion might be true sometimes even when the hypothesis are not true.  It not *required* that $f$ be surjective for the conclusion to be true but if $f$ is surjective then the conclusion *must* be true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The step from

$$\{y\mid y = f(x), f(x) \in H\}$$

to

$$\{y\mid y\in H\}$$

depends on the surjectivity of $f$ - you're saying that every $y \in H$ can be represented as $f(x)$ for some $x \in A$. For comparison, suppose $A = \{0,1\}$, $B = \{0,1\}$, $f(x) = 0$ for all $x$, and $H$ is the set $\{1\}$. Think about what happens to each of your steps in that situation, and where it goes wrong.

Comment: Read this answer closely --- it's a great one!

Comment: Thanks! On the line denoted (1), why  are they able to simply remove the $x \in A$?

Comment: $f$ is defined as a function with domain $A$; if $f(x)$ exists, $x$ is automatically in $A$.

Answer (score 2):

For any $f:A \to B$ and any $H \subseteq B$, $$f[f^{-1}[H]]\subseteq H$$ always holds by definition. For, $y$ in the LHS means $y=f(x)$ for some $x \in f^{-1}[H]$ and $x \in f^{-1}[H]$ iff $f(x) \in H$, so $y \in H$ and inclusion shown.

So in fact $f$ being surjective is equivalent to the other inclusion, so

$$f \text{ surjective } \iff \forall H \subseteq B: H \subseteq f[f^{-1}[H]]$$

and this is what the proof should focus on. The other inclusion is free in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

$f$ *doesn't* need to be surjective to $B$.  You could easily have a $b \in B \setminus H$ so that there is no $a \in A$ so that $f(a) = b$ and this theorem would still be true provided that we restrict $f$ to $f^{-1}(H)$.   That is; if   $f: f^{-1}(H) =  \{a\in A|f(a) \in H\} \to H$ so that  is surjective.

$f(f^{-1}(H) \subset H$ via the proof.  Surjective is *not* required.  *For this half of the proof*.

However surjectivity of $f:f^{-1}(H)\to H$ *is* required.  If there is an $h \in H$ so that no $f(a) = h$ then $h \not \in f(f^{-1}(H))$ and therefore $f(f^{-1}(H) \subsetneq H$.

If surjectivity is required for *any* part of the proof then it is required.  It doesnt have to be required for all parts of the proof.

Comment: You are wrong and that is the definition of $f^{-1}(H)$, regardless of $H$

Comment: Yeah, brain fart on definition of $f^{-1}(H)$.  $f^{-1}(H) = \{a\in A|f(a) \in H\}$.  I was thinking if there is no $a$ so that $f(a) = h$ then $f^{-1}(h)$ doesn't exist.  But $f^{-1}(h) = \emptyset$ is perfectly acceptable.  (Dope slap).  But everything else I said was correct and not "wrong".

Comment: You wrote "I might be wrong" at some point, and you were right about that ;-) (of course the "I might be wrong" only referred to part of your answer, and that's the part I was referring to  as well)

Comment: Yes I was wrong about that.